# How to load bundles with angular-cli?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I must be missing something extremely simple here, because I don't understand how anyone can have a functioning angular-cli app without the ability to do the following...

## Context

I have an Angular 2 app with an express.js backend acting as an API. I have switched from webpack to angular-cli to bundle my files as it offers easy Ahead-Of-Time compilation.

What I didn't expect was angular-cli is so opinionated, it even requires me to keep an index.html file inside the angular app directory in my repository (I had previously kept it in /views for express.js to send to clients).

## Problem

I am struggling to see how I can load the outputted JS bundles from angular-cli if I have node.js server. Consider the following `angular-cli.json` snippet:

```
"apps": [
{
    "root": "app",
    "outDir": "public/dist",
],
```

Both my `bundle.js` files and my `index.html` will be outputted in `public/dist`. This means I have to update my node.js routes to change:

```
// Root
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../views/index.html'));
});
```

to:

```
// Root
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/dist/index.html'));
});
```

Now the problem is that my `public/dist/index.html` file has a `<base href="/">` tag, and the following generated script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Well, obviously when I run my node.js server, those above bundles won't be found because they don't exist at the base href's location. There is no `/inline.bundle.js`, because it's located at `/public/dist/inline.bundle.js`. So, how can I ever load my frontend app?

Comment: Consider using static webserver like `nginx` for static frontend files, that's the way I always do

Answer (score 0):

I don't this will work, as it expect an absolute path, not relative.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/dist/index.html'));
```

You should point in a relative way all the **dist** server to **/** from the express folder, something like:

```
app.use('/', express.static('../public/dist'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '../public/dist' });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I handle this kind of problems in a different way. I never send a file using `sendFile`, instead I only send JSON data.

Sending a file is suitable for traditional non-SPA applications. Sending JSON data is suitable for modern SPA applications.

Comment: Every SPA begins by serving the user with at least an `index.html` file of some kind. Yes, asynchronous requests are required when developing an SPA so you can remove the need to reload pages, but that isn't what I'm asking for or seeking here.